Issues with foundry `forge` unit test vm.expectEmit
I am having some troubles test an events, I expect a bunch of event and test for them but the test is failing and I am not sure why. It pass if I remove all the vm.expectEmit and remove the events it fails when I put them back. here a part of the code.
contract RouterTest is Test {
    Router public router;
    MockRouteProcessor public mockRouteProcessor;
    MockERC20 public mockERC20;

    event Approval(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount);
    event ProcessedRoute(address owner, uint256 amount, address token);
    address owner = address(0x1);
    address addr1 = address(0x2);
    address addr2 = address(0x3);

    function setUp() public {
    ...
    }

    function testForwardERC20Transfer() public {
        uint256 amountIn = 10 ether;

        vm.startPrank(addr1);
        mockERC20.approve(address(router), amountIn);

        console.log(addr1, address(router), amountIn);
  
        vm.expectEmit();
        emit Approval(addr1, address(router), amountIn);

        vm.expectEmit(true, true, true, true);
        emit IERC20.Transfer(addr1, address(router), amountIn);

        vm.expectEmit(true, true, true, true);
        emit IERC20.Approval(addr1, address(router), amountIn);

        vm.expectEmit(true, true, true, true, address(mockRouteProcessor));
        emit ProcessedRoute(addr1, amountIn, address(mockERC20));

        router.forward(
            address(mockERC20),
            amountIn,
            address(mockERC20),
            0,
            addr2,
            ""
        );

        vm.stopPrank();
    }
}

Here is the logs
  [120672] RouterTest::testForwardERC20Transfer()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002)
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [24339] MockERC20::approve(Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, spender: Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], value: 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   └─ ← [Return] true
    ├─ [0] console::log(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], 10000000000000000000 [1e19]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [0] VM::expectEmit()
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, spender: Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], amount: 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    ├─ [0] VM::expectEmit(true, true, true, true)
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, to: Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], value: 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    ├─ [0] VM::expectEmit(true, true, true, true)
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, spender: Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], value: 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    ├─ [0] VM::expectEmit(true, true, true, true, MockRouteProcessor: [0x535B3D7A252fa034Ed71F0C53ec0C6F784cB64E1])
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ emit ProcessedRoute(sender: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, amount: 10000000000000000000 [1e19], tokenIn: MockERC20: [0x522B3294E6d06aA25Ad0f1B8891242E335D3B459])
    ├─ [64078] Router::forward(MockERC20: [0x522B3294E6d06aA25Ad0f1B8891242E335D3B459], 10000000000000000000 [1e19], MockERC20: [0x522B3294E6d06aA25Ad0f1B8891242E335D3B459], 0, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003, 0x)
    │   ├─ [30220] MockERC20::transferFrom(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, to: Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], value: 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   │   └─ ← [Return] true
    │   ├─ [24339] MockERC20::approve(MockRouteProcessor: [0x535B3D7A252fa034Ed71F0C53ec0C6F784cB64E1], 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], spender: MockRouteProcessor: [0x535B3D7A252fa034Ed71F0C53ec0C6F784cB64E1], value: 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   │   └─ ← [Return] true
    │   ├─ [2094] MockRouteProcessor::processRoute(MockERC20: [0x522B3294E6d06aA25Ad0f1B8891242E335D3B459], 10000000000000000000 [1e19], MockERC20: [0x522B3294E6d06aA25Ad0f1B8891242E335D3B459], 0, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003, 0x)
    │   │   ├─ emit ProcessedRoute(sender: Router: [0xc051134F56d56160E8c8ed9bB3c439c78AB27cCc], amount: 10000000000000000000 [1e19], tokenIn: MockERC20: [0x522B3294E6d06aA25Ad0f1B8891242E335D3B459])
    │   │   └─ ← [Return] 10000000000000000000 [1e19]
    │   └─ ← [Return] 10000000000000000000 [1e19]
    └─ ← [Revert] log != expected log


Please add the definition of the pepperRouter.forward function to your question.

You need to write these two events in the test script, as you have done with other events, to ensure it works correctly.

        vm.expectEmit(true, true, true, true);
        emit IERC20.Transfer(addr1, address(router), amountIn);

        vm.expectEmit(true, true, true, true);
        emit IERC20.Approval(addr1, address(router), amountIn);


You need to specify the list expect emit event and your execution in right orders. You will need to expect emit before execution.
In your code, you're expecting Approval after execute approve, you need to move it to before.
vm.expectEmit();
emit Approval(addr1, address(router), amountIn);

vm.startPrank(addr1);
mockERC20.approve(address(router), amountIn);  

